# Shell script error; unexpected

Tags: shell

I have a script that loops over my files, combine two files and run a python script. However, if I run this, I get a error:

```
Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "done")
```

What is wrong with my script?

```
#!/bin/sh
for file1 in *R1*fastq
do 
    file2=${file1/R1/R2}
    out=${file1%%.fastq}_output
    python spades.py --careful -1 $file1 -2 $file2 -o $out 
done
```

Comment: Almost certainly your file format has DOS newlines or other hidden characters. That would make the `done` instead be parsed as `$'done\r'`, with a CR at the end, and so a different word.

Comment: BTW, there are other bugs here that you'll probably only detect when dealing with unusual filenames. Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: I did like you suggest and now I have the error "bad substitution" for line 4. Do you know how that is happening? I already tried to run dos2unix before running the script.

Comment: That's an unrelated error: `#!/bin/sh` doesn't support `${var/old/new}`. You need a more capable shell -- use `#!/bin/bash`.